# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to UserPrincipal

Tags: spring, spring-security

I made this class UserPrincipal to get the user id of my custom Hibernate User class.

```
public class UserPrincipal extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public UserPrincipal(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
            boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, User user) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
        this.user = user;
    }

    private final User user;

}
```

However, when I use it like this:

```
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    User user = ((UserPrincipal) principal).getUser();
```

I get the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to UserPrincipal

I think there's an error in the way I implemented the constructor, but I am not sure.

Or does it have to do with a mismatch with the way I log the user in? I am using Spring Security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of extending user class from spring-security you better to implement UserDetails interface given from spring security. please read the below code. Provide custom userDetailsService implementation to your project. i hope this will help you- http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html#d0e1613

```
  public class LoggedUser implements UserDetails{
  private User user;
  // setter and getter of user 

  public LoggedUser (User user){
  this.user=user;

  }



public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities=new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
for (String role : user.getRoles()) {
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
}
return authorities;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
return user.getPassword();
  }

   public String getUsername() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return user.getUsername();
  }

  public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return true;
   }

   public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return true;
  }

   public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return true;
  }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
 }
```

now User the below code to get User object:

```
   LoggedUser principal = (LoggedUser)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
User user = pricipal.getUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is classic case of downcasting. To achieve this, do the following:
Let consider A is the super class and B is sub class:

1. Define this method in the subclass(B):

   public static B method(A a) {
        B b = null;
        if (a instanceof A) {
            b = (B) a;// downcasting

        }
        return b;
    }

2. Now in your working class(e.g., Service, Controller etc), do the following


    A b = new B(); // Initialize super class object with subclass
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(a,b);//where a being the instance of A(user in your case), with values
    B c = B.method(b);
```

Comment: So I just need to downcast UserPrincipal to User?

Comment: Can't do the following: (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

Comment: Wait, the whole point of what I was trying to do was to get the userId from the custom class User. If I need to create a and pass an instance of User with the userId inside it, that defeats the whole point of what I was trying to do.

Answer (score -2):

just check the user ur logged in with ur security user DB.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).